# "Aэропорт "Домодедово" - why not genitve?

Tags: грамматика, падежи

When we form a noun phrase, we use either adjectives or genitive case. For
example;

> красная машина -> feminine adjective + feminine noun (red car)
>
> цвет цветка -> nominative case + genitive case (color of flower)

I came across this phrase:

`аэропорт Домодедово`

The translation of this phrase is `airport` **of** `Domodedovo`.
So we need to use genitive case. But `Домодедово` is not in genitive case. Why?

Comment: it should be `аэропорт "Домодедово"` - with the quotes - I believe, meaning `airport named "Domodedovo"`

Answer (score 11):

*Домодедово* is the proper name of the airport, which is technically called *Москва (Домодедово)*. It's not an "airport serving Domodedovo" (although it does serve it among other cities of course), it's an airport called "Domodedovo".

If we were speaking about, say, "Domodedovo government" (*администрация Домодедова*) or "Domodedovo police" (*полиция Домодедова*), we would have used genitive indeed.

However, lately, Russian tends to drop declination of names in *-ово, -ево, -ино, -ыно* to avoid confusion with masculine names in oblique cases (*в Пушкине* could mean both "in Pushkin, St. Petersburg" and "in Pushkino, Moscow oblast"). So you can hear and read *администрация Домодедово* and *полиция Домодедово* just as often nowadays.

Answer (score 4):

The rules about toponyms and such are a bit complicated and not too consistent in general. But, as a rule of thumb, Genitive case signifies that an object belongs or somehow dedicated to another one. E.g. *улица Моцарта*, *площадь Революции* etc.

But here we have an airport *of Moscow* named Domodedovo because of its location, while *Аэропорт Домодедова*, as you propose, would naturally be understood as an airport of town Domodedovo.